# Is this sentence right? It is from my exercise book

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, verbs

"The evidence that the flower in the greenhouse failing to endure any storms indicates that kids should never be spoiled too much."

This sentence is the answer of an translation question which I found in a English exercise book. The question required me to translate a sentence from my native language to English. And I doubt the "failing" in this sentence, I think there must be something wrong.

Is this sentence right or wrong? If it is wrong, could you show the right one?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I think the first part of your sentence needs a verb. *"The evidence that the flower in the greenhouse **is** failing (or fails) to..."*

Comment: My viewpoint is the same with you, but my friend's wasn't. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your example sentence

> The evidence that the flower in the greenhouse failing to endure any storms indicates that kids should never be spoiled too much.

Is grammatical, but a bit awkward.

It might be said as

> The evidence that **a** flower **grown** in **a** greenhouse **fails** to endure any storms indicates that kids should never be spoiled too much.

since the author is not speaking about a *particular* flower or greenhouse

or

> The evidence **of** greenhouse flowers, failing to endure any storms, indicates that kids should never be spoiled too much.

Comment: Thanks! My friends and I were confused about this sentence and argued for a long time.